# Cross cloud storage integration in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need information if cross cloud storage integration is allowed in Snowflake.

Scenario :: My Snowflake account is hosted on AWS(Standard edition) & is operated out of US-West, and I am trying to load the data from GCS bucket into Snowflake.

What I am trying to do is like below using 'accountadmin' role::

```
CREATE STORAGE INTEGRATION integration_testing
TYPE = EXTERNAL_STAGE
STORAGE_PROVIDER = GCS
ENABLED = TRUE
STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('<gcs_bucket_path');
```

Error which I get :: "SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 370001:1828601086; incident 2272255.".   Everytime it is creating an incident.

What can be possible reasons or any suggestion to mitigate this? Also need to know ad understand whether cross cloud integration is possible or not.

Comment: Reading on that error it seems 370001 is related to permissions. Perhaps your GCS permissions are not correct

Comment: I've done this many times without problem, as @DeanFlinter says - you might need to follow the instructions to make that bucket readable by the account (should be easy)

Comment: Thanks much !!  This worked now as there was an issue with GCS set-up.

Answer (score 0):

> What can be possible reasons or any suggestion to mitigate this?

You need to submit a ticket to Snowflake Support. It seems there is an issue with creating credentials for Google Integration.

> Also need to know ad understand whether cross cloud integration is
> possible or not.

Yes, it's possible.